# Why is this recent highly upvoted icon suggestion question not closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

I was flabbergasted to see this question: [I'm designing a no-data USB cable : How should the end be marked?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/103552/im-designing-a-no-data-usb-cable-how-should-the-end-be-marked) not only in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar, but receiving many upvotes, and not being closed.

In trying to understand why this question I asked was closed ([Universal rideshare icon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/100756/universal-rideshare-icon)), in the context of this new question.

The explanatory text for why my question was closed was:

> "Questions requesting Icon Suggestions are off topic. While the subject of icons is on topic, there's very little value in soliciting suggestions for a specific icon in a specific context. See this meta post for more information about this topic."

The no-data USB question makes such remarks as:

> What graphic treatment might work, so consumers don't confuse this with a full USB cable capable of transmitting data?

and

> I've checked with the USB implementors forum, and there's no standard logo for this case.

How does this not meet the same criteria that was used as rational to close my icon question? The no-data USB question is just as specific of an application as my ride-sharing icon question, if not more so.

Again, I am just trying to get a better understanding of the consistency of enforcement of the topic of questions on this site.

Comment: Yeah, and why it got so much attention ? 20k views for icon suggestion topic?

Answer (score 5):

IMO, this question is not asking just for an icon.

There are multiple ways to possibly indicate to a user that the cable is different than others (reading the answers, we find suggestions of all kinds: icons, color, cable texture, cable stiffness, wording). Sure, some solutions *might* be icons.

I believe there's a difference between **asking how to effectively communicate** the cable's distinctive quality to the user and **asking for an icon** that means no data.

---

I saw this happen with [another question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/97246/communicate-session-is-about-to-expire-without-words) a little while ago--people wanted to close it because they thought it was just asking for icons. Turns out the OP was pleased with an answer that didn't mention icons at all...